# How to distribute portfolios to portfolio managers with Blackbox Multi-Objective Optimization Python packages?

Tags: python, optimization, finance, portfolio

I am new to optimization questions, and I am looking for a Python package for the following question:

There are 15 portfolio managers (PM) and 300 portfolio accounts. Each account has a unique complexity score Xn (0<Xn<1) and an index. There are 40 indexes in total, so some accounts have the same indexes.

**Goal:** minimize the sum of the indexes for each PM.

**Constraints:** Each PM has a complexity score within +/- 10% of the target score (target score is the average complexity score for a PM).

I have been searching all over but didn't find any similar questions. Really appreciate it if anyone can point me the direction on a potential Python package or similar paper.

Edit:
Adding an example to clarify the question. Here is what the table looks like:

```py
    Portfolio   Index   Complexity
0      A          x        0.1
1      B          y        0.2
2      C          z        0.3
3      D          z        0.4
```

The approach I can think of is using "more_itertools" to return all possible combinations.

```py
from more_itertools import set_partitions

pd.DataFrame(list(set_partitions(df.Portfolio,3)))


    PM1      PM2     PM3
0   [A]      [B]    [C,D]
1   [A]      [B,C]  [D]
2   [A]      [C]    [B,D]
3   [A,B]    [C]    [D]
4   [B]      [A,C]  [D]
5   [B]      [C]    [A,D]
```

From above, each row (combination), portfolio manager has different number of indexes and average complexity score. The goal is to minize the indexes number for each PM with their complexity score land in the range.

Comment: `There are 40 indexes in total ... Goal: minimize the sum of the indexes for each PM.` Can you explain more about this step? Why would moving an account from one PM to another PM change the sum of indexes? Some accounts have the same indexes - so how do you compute the sum of indexes in that case? Are both counted?

Comment: *How to distribute portfolios to portfolio managers with Blackbox Multi-Objective Optimization Python packages?* Why "Blackbox Multi-Objective Optimization"?  The described problem has a single objective and is not a black box. I have no idea why one would choose a solver like that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I have tried to clarify the question with an example. Sorry if this can't be solved with optimization, but I really hope to get some ideas on how to solve this question... Anything will help. Thanks again!

Comment: The total sum of the indices is constant as all portfolios have to be assigned. So that is not a useful objective. This is more like a (variant of) an assignment problem. It often helps to first write down the mathematical model.

Comment: Note that say a MIP formulation (using a MIP solver) will certainly be much faster than complete enumeration using itertools.